# How can I implement shell job control basics in Python?

Tags: python, bash, shell, unix, job-control

There is basic job control like suspend, resume, interrupt, and background implemented by most modern shells.

How can I make a shell sensitive to ^Z, fg, ^C, and bg (as they appear in bash), in Python? Or what should I be reading?

Comment: You are implementing a shell in Python?

Comment: Are you talking about the interactive mode?

Comment: If you are looking for more advanced key input, and shell read/write of charactors, see ncurses.

Comment: Yes, or at least I'm trying: http://JonathansCorner.com/cjsh

Answer (score 0):

No need to do anything :

```
python -c 'import time; time.sleep(600)'
```

You can test all your keyboard combos ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can capture signals sent to your program using `signal` module. For instance `^Z` means `SIGTSTP` in Unix like systems.

```
import signal
jobs = []

def handler(signum, frame):
    jobs.append(frame)

signal.signal(signal.SIGTSTP, handler)
```

Now when you type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> `handler` will be called and print "catch". You can capture `^C` using `signal.SIGINT`.